# Proof package: lines too short

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, rules

The `proof` package's `\infer` command automatically sizes the lines it draws.

However, it isn't always right (pdflatex output):

> [image]

The line is too short on the left.

Is this a package bug/inaccuracy, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code (MWE made) that produced the document above:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{proof}
%
\begin{document}
\[
 \infer{\bot}{
   \infer{P}{
     \infer{P \vee P}{
       P \vee Q
       \quad
       P \vee \neg Q
     }
   }
  \qquad
  \infer{\neg P}{
   \infer{\neg P \vee \neg P}{
     \neg P \vee Q
     \quad
     \neg P \vee \neg Q
   }
  }
 }
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: After looking for some implementation code for `\infer`, and not finding anything; I suggest that the third line is space-sensitive. Since the right column is larger (added negative symbols) than the left, it is "read" as incomplete, thus is made shorter at the base connection. By intuition, my advice is to substitute in the left column code `\quad` with `\qquad`, this will add horizontal space and the line will cover the letter base.

Comment: You might have a look at `bussproofs.sty` of which you find a guide at http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a look at `bussproofs.sty`; you find also an [online guide](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/)

Here's a comparison (I added `\qquad` as suggested by Andrea L. for making the first line slightly wider)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$P\lor Q$} \AxiomC{$P\lor\lnot Q$}
\BinaryInfC{$P\lor P$}
\UnaryInfC{$P$}
\AxiomC{$\lnot P\lor Q$} \AxiomC{$\lnot P\lor \lnot Q$}
\BinaryInfC{$\lnot P\lor\lnot P$}
\UnaryInfC{$\lnot P$}
\BinaryInfC{$\bot$}
\end{prooftree}
\[
 \infer{\bot}{
   \infer{P}{
     \infer{P \vee P}{
       P \vee Q
       \qquad
       P \vee \neg Q
     }
   }
  \qquad
  \infer{\neg P}{
   \infer{\neg P \vee \neg P}{
     \neg P \vee Q
     \quad
     \neg P \vee \neg Q
   }
  }
 }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to have left a useful suggestion posted inside an answer!

Comment: @AndreaL. You may add your answer based on `proof`

Comment: The only thing that is stopping me to do that is the lack of documentation, since I do not know any buliding feature of `\infer` I don't want to leave tips that my cause errors with other situations.